# How to Configure Private Endpoint for Azure Synapse Spark Pool?

Tags: azure, apache-spark, azure-synapse

I have created the Spark Pool for Azure Synapse and I want to configure the Private Endpoint

```
resource "azurerm_synapse_spark_pool" "synapse-spark-pool" {
  name                 = "synapse-spark-pool"
  synapse_workspace_id = azurerm_synapse_workspace.synapsews.id
  node_size_family     = "MemoryOptimized"
  node_size            = "Small"
  cache_size           = 100

  auto_scale {
    max_node_count = 1
    min_node_count = 1
  }

  auto_pause {
    delay_in_minutes = 15
  }

  library_requirement {
    content  = <<EOF
appnope==0.1.0
beautifulsoup4==4.6.3
EOF
    filename = "requirements.txt"
  }

  spark_config {
    content  = <<EOF
spark.shuffle.spill                true
EOF
    filename = "config.txt"
  }

  tags = {
    ENV = "Production"
  }
}
```

I have the following Private DNS Zone created.

1. privatelink.sql.azuresynapse.net
2. privatelink.dev.azuresynapse.net
3. privatelink.azuresynapse.net

Is there any other Private DNS Zone to be created? and what are all the Private Endpoints to be created to support the Private Endpoint for Spark Pools in Azure Synapse?

Comment: Have you found answer to this question?